# Binding multiple sources to a Listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I am using a List to bind a Listbox in my application. But I need to add an extrafield which is not present in the bound object. I am not getting idea how to do it. Any idea please??

My code:

```
ObservableCollection<LatestItemsInfo> lstLatestItem;
lstBoxLatestItems.ItemsSource = lstLatestItem;

CurrencyInfo info = new CurrencyInfo();
        info.CurrencySymbol = "$";
```

I need to add this currencysymbol to my listbox:

My listbox is like this:

```
<ListBox Name="lstBoxLatestItems">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel Height="160" Width="160" Margin="0">
                                <Image Height="150" Width="150" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="160" Margin="10" Width="300">

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding info}">
                                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding CurrencySymbol}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding ListPrice}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

What logic determines what currency symbol is to be displayed?  Is there complex logic for that?  Without knowing anything about this logic, I can try and suggest a solution though.

There's two main ways you would generally go about this.

1. Wrap each object in the collection you're binding to in another object that adds the property. The wrapper object could inherit from the "base" object, and simply add the property.
2. Use a value converter.  Pass the whole object (or just a property, depending on what's required by the logic that determines the currency symbol to display).  Return the correct currency symbol from the value converter.

Hope this helps...

Chris Anderson

Comment: i have already got the currency symbol.. i just need to display it on the textblock. So can you help me with the code...

Comment: Well the code depends on the logic involved in determining the correct currency symbol.  Here's a blog post about value converters. http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Either go with a converter, as suggested by Chris Anderson, or do something like the following

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding CurrencySymbol}" />
    <Run Text="{Binding Price}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Note that this assumes the CurrencySymbol is a property of your `LatestItemsInfo` object.  If not, adjust the binding accordingly.